# How to add "read more" to category description in product listing page in Magento 2.2.4?

Tags: admin, magento2.2.2

I don't know how to implement this task. I have used in smart wave and Porto theme. I want to add read more in the category description. Can you please help me?

Comment: I have achieved this by  : https://kswedberg.github.io/jquery-expander/

Comment: This works for me: https://www.jqueryscript.net/text/Read-More-Less-Buttons.html

Comment: I have created it for you. Please check my answer it will help you.

Comment: if my answer solves your concern then there is green right tick mark, hit that tickmark for right answer that will help future readers.

Answer (score 3):

I just created it and its working for me.

Overrider `description.phtml` file from `module-catalog` core module.

Copy below the file inside your theme.

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/category/description.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * Category view template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View
 */
?>
<?php if ($_description = $block->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
    <div class="category-description more">
        <?php
        $string = strip_tags($this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->categoryAttribute($block->getCurrentCategory(), $_description, 'description'));

        if (strlen($string) > 100) {
            $stringCut = substr($string, 0, 100);
            $string = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' ')).'... <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="readmore">Read More</a>';
        }

        echo $string;
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="less" style="display:none">
        <?php echo $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->categoryAttribute($block->getCurrentCategory(), $_description, 'description'); ?>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="readless">Read Less</a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        require(["jquery"],function($){
            //console.log('testte');
            //alert('test');
            $('.readmore').on("click",function(){
                $('.less').show();
                $('.more').hide();
            });
            $('.readless').on("click",function(){
                $('.less').hide();
                $('.more').show();
            });
        });
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You can modify as you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Im trying to use following script

https://codepen.io/maxds/pen/jgeoA

I have altered the .more to .category-description but i dont know how to put it into the "Magento2" requirement.. 
with that require jquery and so on.
could someone help?

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Configure/customize these variables.
    var showChar = 100;  // How many characters are shown by default
    var ellipsestext = "...";
    var moretext = "Show more >";
    var lesstext = "Show less";

```
$('.more').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).html();

    if(content.length > showChar) {

        var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
        var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);

        var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

        $(this).html(html);
    }

});

$(".morelink").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
        $(this).removeClass("less");
        $(this).html(moretext);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("less");
        $(this).html(lesstext);
    }
    $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
    $(this).prev().toggle();
    return false;
});
```

});

AND FOR CSS:

.morecontent span {
    display: none;
}
.morelink {
    display: block;
}